# Installing turtlebot on ROS kinetic

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a master computer to control my turtlebot. My master computer has ubuntu 16.04 xenial, so I was wondering whether turtlebot will work with it and if it does, how to install turtlebot for xenial. In most of the tutorials it says turtlebot is supported for only ROS indigo, so what do I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246015/installing-turtlebot-on-ros-kinetic/) by [homagni](https://answers.ros.org/users/28290/homagni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot packages have been released for Kinetic.

See the tutorials here: http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [homagni](https://answers.ros.org/users/28290/homagni/) on 2016-10-19**:
the tutorials all point to ros indigo..do I just blindly follow them for ROS kinetic too? Wont there be any changes for installing turtlebot for ROS kinetic? Can you please paste the link to the instructions?
Thanking you

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-19**:
Generally everything that worked in indigo is expected to work in kinetic. Just replace the keywords and use Xenial instead of Trusty.

**Comment by [homagni](https://answers.ros.org/users/28290/homagni/) on 2016-10-19**:
Do I need to replace keyword indigo with keywords like kinetic anywhere?

**Comment by [Eric_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25481/eric_ros/) on 2016-11-21**:
Hello~ all
I also have the same problems to install Turtlebot packages on ROS-kinetic.
I followed instruction to install turtlebot deb by replacing indigo to kinetic.
but still some errors there...

Any obvious solution for this ? thank you!

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-05-08**:
Replacing `indigo` with `kinetic` in the current tutorial install line fails due to `ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon` and `ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library` not being found. Removing them works though might impact some functionality.

**Comment by [srf](https://answers.ros.org/users/32230/srf/) on 2017-10-13**:
How did you get on with this? I have the same issue and I am worried I will run into problems down the line.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-11-08**:
@srf I don't know! I might have abandoned as I don't recall doing much with the turtlebot. That said, the other day followed along with a tutorial and launched a turtlebot in a gazebo and it worked, so maybe it updated itself away?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got everything up and running with these scripts: https://bitbucket.org/damienjadeduff/456_kinetic_turtlebot/src/b8eacebf174b?at=master

---

Originally posted by [vegetish](https://answers.ros.org/users/29570/vegetish/) with karma: 21 on 2017-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vegetish](https://answers.ros.org/users/29570/vegetish/) on 2017-03-05**:
Albeit some packages not working, like the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to get mine working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I had a similar issue because I was using Anaconda :(
I  tried a bunch of solutions but the most recent one that worked was `pip install defusedxml` . I also did a bunch of wildcard installs `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot*` and on "ros-kinetic-kobuki". Hope it solves your problem

---

Originally posted by [Lxrd-AJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29823/lxrd-aj/) with karma: 11 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

This thread also exists here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/249348/installing-turtlebot-for-kinetic/

I submitted my solution to it, but thought it might be appreciated here too, so here's a convenience copy:

---

I was really having trouble getting this to work, FINALLY found out how to get turtlebot to install cleanly on kinetic!

#TLDR;

### Do this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted" > \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-librealsense
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-librealsense-camera
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-turtlebot
```

### Or [see my full ROS setup script](https://github.com/stillgreyfox/setup/tree/ros_master_x86)

---

## Here's my route to the solution:

First hint came from doing a wildcard turtlebot install attempt

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot*
```

This gave me a gem in that it told me why it couldn't install the -bringup package:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup : Depends: ros-kinetic-realsense-camera but it is not going to be installed
```

#### Dern you RealSense!

Going further down the rabbit hole, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-realsense-camera
```

Got this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-realsense-camera : Depends: ros-kinetic-librealsense but it is not going to be installed
```

Next, you guessed it, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-librealsense
```

Surprise, surprise...

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-kinetic-librealsense : Depends: linux-headers-generic but it is not going to be installed
```

Finally, one from the distro that will work!

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

BUT! It's not THAT easy... You also need to enable the source repositories, since installing ros-kinetic-librealsense incurs a compilation which requires your kernel sources, so from the [ROS docs](http://wiki.ros.org/librealsense#Enable_Kernel_Sources), we can see how to do this, or you can copy me

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted" > \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, magic happens! (assuming you have typical compilers installed)

(Optional)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

Let's try this again

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-librealsense
```

It should build, you may see some warnings, but as long as it completes OK, you can continue back up out of the rabbit hole

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-realsense-camera
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot
```

#### Yay! turtlebot on kinetic!

---

Originally posted by [stillgreyfox](https://answers.ros.org/users/30375/stillgreyfox/) with karma: 41 on 2017-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SeanTronathon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31081/seantronathon/) on 2017-07-09**:
It would appear that your "Do this:" box of instructions is already a bit outdated. I just successfully followed all of your steps omitting `sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-librealsense-camera` since this package no longer exists. But the ros-kinetic-turtlebot install worked anyway. Just FYI.

**Comment by [tranvannhancu](https://answers.ros.org/users/36103/tranvannhancu/) on 2018-06-26**:
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot*
This works well for me on Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic. No further installation is required.

**Comment by [kasptom](https://answers.ros.org/users/35272/kasptom/) on 2019-08-04**:
If someone is getting an error like `Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu <YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION>/main amd64 <SOME_ROS_PKG> amd64 0.13.3-0xenial-20190320-132757-0800 404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]`, see this: [apt update fails / cannot install pkgs: key not working?](https://answers.ros.org/question/325039/apt-update-fails-cannot-install-pkgs-key-not-working/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot-*
```

Should do the job for you.

---

Originally posted by [Luthais](https://answers.ros.org/users/52824/luthais/) with karma: 11 on 2020-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Al53](https://answers.ros.org/users/30273/al53/) on 2020-08-09**:
Trying this with Ubuntu 16.04 as a one line command triggered the following error: “ros-kinetic-librealsense uvcvideo kernel module failed to build”